# How can remove timestamp suffix for the snapshot dependency jar when mvn install?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a project `A` depenes `bean-0.01-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

When I exec `mvn install`, a jar named like `bean-0.01-20180111.054629-147.jar` will be assembled into `A.war`.

How can I assembly `bean-0.01-SNAPSHOT.jar` into `A.war` after I exec `mvn install`?

Comment: What make file name change from `bean-0.01-SNAPSHOT.jar` to `bean-0.01-20180111.054629-147.jar`?

Comment: This is the correct behaviour, a snapshot jar contains the timestamp in its name.  When you will release a stable version of bean.jar the war will contains the file with the name bean-0.01.jar.